# Warum ist es zur Rechten und nicht immer zum Recht/e?

Tags: declension

In einer meiner Lesungen stieß ich auf Folgendes:

> zur Rechten

was keinen Sinn ergibt für mich. [Recht](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/recht:N:N:modern) kann nur in ein Kasus sein: zum Recht([29 Beispiele](https://context.reverso.net/translation/german-english/zum+Recht)) oder oder im seltenen Plural zu den Rechten ([66 Beispiele](https://context.reverso.net/translation/german-english/zu+den+Rechten)) aber auf magische Weise erscheint das neutrale Wort ([75 Mal](https://context.reverso.net/translation/german-english/zur+Rechten)) in grammatikalisch inkorrekter Form(Meiner Meinung nach). Hat jemand eine Erklärung?

Vollständiger Kontext von "Der Zauberberg" von Thomas Mann:

> man sah die vorderen Wagen, sah die Maschine, die in ihrer Mühe
>   braune, grüne und schwarze Rauchmassen ausstieß, die verflatterten.
>   Wasser rauschten in der Tiefe **zur Rechten**; links strebten dunkle
>   Fichten zwischen Felsblöcken gegen einen steingrauen Himmel empor.

Comment: Wir brauchen mehr Kontext! Den ganzen Satz, bitte.

Comment: "zur Rechten" is short for "zur rechten Hand" = "on the right side". Strictly, the 'r' should be uncapitalized, but even us Germans don't understand those rules very well.

Comment: @user unknown Ich habe nicht das genaue Zitat, aber im Kontext bezog es sich auf Richtungen nicht das Gesetz.

Comment: @user5389726598465: Das ist wichtig und gehört in die Frage. "Zur Rechten" könnte, wie "Zur Blonden" auch ein Kneipenname sein oder eine Frage, ob man zu einer politisch rechts stehenden Frau gehen will, oder einem weiblichen Ort oder Ereignis (Fankurve, Diskussionsveranstaltung, ...).

Comment: @userunknown ok, aktualisiert

Comment: @KilianFoth I have to condradict you there, the r is capitalized because "Rechten" is used as a noun here. It is like "der Erste" compared to "der erste Mann".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Die Ausdrücke haben unterschiedliche Bedeutungen, beziehen sich insbesondere aber bereits auch auf unterschiedliche Substantive.

- *zum Recht* bezieht sich auf das Substantiv *(das) Recht* ([DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Recht))
- *zur Rechten* bezieht sich auf das Substantiv *(die) Rechte* ([DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Rechte#1))

*Zur Rechten* ist ein gängiger Ausdruck für "auf der rechten Seite": *Zur Rechten sehen Sie das Brandenburger Tor. Der Baum zur Rechten ist eine Eiche.*

Comment: "Zur rechten" mit Groß-R? Kilian sagt "klein".

Comment: @userunknown "Rech|te, die; -n, -n _(rechte Hand; rechte Seite; Politik die rechts stehenden Parteien, eine rechts stehende Gruppe)_; **zur Rechten**; in meiner Rechten; er traf ihn mit einer blitzschnellen Rechten (Boxen); [...]" (Duden, Die deutsche Rechtschreibung, 27. Aufl. 2017; eigene Hervorhebung)

Comment: Du hast eine Quelle, du hast gewonnen. :) Auch wenn der Duden nicht in allen Fragen normativ ist; in solchen ist er meist verlässlich. Außerdem wird es durch das Mannzitat gedeckt und ich glaube die Manns waren eher pedantisch in solchen Fragen.